# Making Application For HomePod

Tags: ios, applet, siri, sirikit

I have a requirement of making an application which runs on HomePod. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to develop apps for the HomePod at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please give some idea on it . My requirement is to make an application which can work from homepod . How can I do that.

Comment: You can't.  There are no APIs for Siri on the HomePod at this time.

Comment: I do research on it. My thinking is that We can do it by using Sirikit framework on our application. What do you think?

Comment: You can trigger a sirikit intent from the HomePod but the app runs on the paired iPhone, not on the HomePod.  The paired phone must be on the same network as the HomePod and you are limited to the interaction types supported by SiriKit intents. Depending on what you actually want to do, it may work for you.